# Getting an Unexpected identifier at createScript error

Tags: javascript, arrays, error-handling, stack-trace

Why am I getting an error for this code? All I want to do is return an array containing the multiples of the arguments.

```
function multiplyByTwo(a,b,c){
 //we have two variables i and ar which is an array
 var i,ar=[];
 //for loop cycles through 0-2 and multiplies each by two
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
//  arguments[3] // Takes the arguem Follows array indexing notations. 
//at i=0, ar[0]=arguments[0]*2, arguments[0]=a*2
//at i=1, ar[1]=arguments[1]*2, arguments[1]=b*2
//at i=2, ar[2]=arguments[2]*2, arguments[2]=c*2
ar[i]=arguments[i]*2;
    }
 return ar;
}

var result=multiplyByTwo(1,2,3);



Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
```

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<3;i++){` Vanilla JS has no `int`. In the future you can figure out the problem yourself by looking at the line the error refers to

Comment: Should be `for (var i = 0; ...)`

Comment: Ahh,thanks, habits of java lol

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the people in the comments, the main reason for the error is there is no `int` in `JS`. There are a few improvements/suggestions to refactor your code as below:

```
function multiplyByTwo(...args){
  var i,ar=[];

  for(let i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
    ar[i]=arguments[i]*2;
  }
 return ar;
}

var result=multiplyByTwo(1,2,3,4);
```

First, method `multiplyByTwo(...args)`. Using `Spread syntax` makes your function receive dynamic number of parameters instead of hardcoding to 3 fixed length, which improves scalability of your function.

Since you are using the keywords `arguments`, to keep it consistent, instead of looping exactly 3 times, replace it with `arguments.length` instead and it will compliment `...args` which suggested earlier. Of course there are other even simpler and shorter syntax available to achieve what you're doing as below

```
function multiplyByTwo(...args){
  return [...args].map(x => x * 2);
}

var result=multiplyByTwo(1,2,3,4);
console.log(result)
```